# About Schengen Visa 180 days rule

Tags: schengen, 90-180-visa-rules

I have been issued 1 schengen visa for 20 days stay with one month validity in month of may 2016. I have been in Schengen for 7 days i.e from 19 May 2016-25 May 2016 was my stay.
Then again i have been issued second schengen visa for 30 days stay with 3 months validity in month of july 2016. I am in Schengen now and will exit on 04 sep 2016 and hence 28 days of stay will be used.For your reference,
My stay is from 08 aug 2016-04 sep 2016.

My question is now that how this 180 days rule work, this rule is applicable and vanish after the new visa gets issued or it remains with all visas or from the first entry.
Like i have to apply new visa now once i come back to india on 4 sep.
So, how my 180 days rule gonna work.
Can someone make me clear about this situation?
Like My 180 days will be counted from my 1 visa entry i.e 19 may or from my 2 visa entry date i.e 08 aug 2016

Answer (score 2):

The 90/180 rule for Schengen C visa has no start date, and it applies to all C visa. At any day you are in the Schengen area, you you must not have stayed more than 90 days out of the preceding 180 in the area.

- In the 180 days from May 19th to November 14th, you can spend 90 days in Schengen. Your two trips account for 35 days, so you have 55 days left provided you can get a new C visa.
- In the 180 days from May 20th to November 15th, you can spend 90 days in Schengen. Your two trips account for 34 days, so you have 56 days left provided you can get a new C visa.
- And so on.

Comment: So, that mean after November 15 if i take any entry in schengen , that entry in schengen would not be having any relation with my may entry as it would not fall in my preceeding 180 days ?

Comment: @KartikAgarwal, the Schengen rules consider each day of your visit separately. On November 15th your stay on May 19th no longer counts because it was more than 180 days ago, but your stay on May 20th still does because it was 180 days ago.

Comment: Its a rolling 180 days window, your last 180 days from today

Comment: @DavChana, that's what I explained. In The first trip of the OP "rolls" out of the window.